# Unable to fetch access token mule <-> salesforce

Tags: oauth, mule, esb

I am stuck in something which i thought it is gonna be a very easy one.

I am trying to setup a Mule flow to connect with Salesforce and get OAUTH token.

```
<flow>
 <sfdc:config-with-oauth consumerKey="thatgirliscute" consumerSecret="nosheishOT" doc:name="Salesforce (OAuth)" name="Salesforce__OAuth_" connectionTimeout="10000" readTimeout="10000">
        <sfdc:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8081" path="callback"/>
    </sfdc:config-with-oauth>

    <flow name="salesforce-oauthFlow1" doc:name="salesforce-oauthFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>

        <sfdc:authorize accessTokenUrl="https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token" authorizationUrl="https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize" config-ref="Salesforce__OAuth_" display="PAGE" doc:name="Authorize at Salesforce"/>
    </flow>
```

But I get an error message saying 'Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: String'

```
Message               : Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Connection timed out: connect (java.net.ConnectException)
  java.net.PlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
2. Error found while consuming http resource at https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token (java.lang.RuntimeException)
  org.mule.security.oauth.util.HttpUtilImpl:93 (null)
3. Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.security.oauth.processor.OAuth2FetchAccessTokenMessageProcessor:91 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Any pointers to resolve is of great help. thanks

-- EDIT : I am behind a corporate firewall - does it matters ? But i am able to successfully do the basic authentication with Salesforce connector. Only OAuTH is leading to a problem.

When i type in localhost:8081 i get redirected to

https://ap1.salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=l86Hcy6qEKtWNqzXVErZDlmcRQs0D_HBE55Mqtm_Al6fTUPSfuQ%3D%3D&display=page&sdtd=1

and then redirected automatically to below URL with error 'Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: String' in the browser and the console reads as i have posted above.

http://localhost:8081/callback?display=page&code=aPrxaSyVmC8fBbfefEfQB5xrKXrrRhK3DiVFrPu5ia0Q%3D%3D&state=%3C%3CMULE_EVENT_ID%3D0-546bdbb1-0095-11e5-9fcb-2c4138b080c9%3E%3E

Comment: It seems to be connection Timeout. Increase the time out and try whether it is throwing out the same error even then.

Comment: @star thanks for the comment - the current time out is 1000 seconds .. but still i see this error

Comment: In the config above, the timeout is `10000` milliseconds, that's `10` seconds... The firewall shouldn't be an issue because all calls are originating from the inside to the outside world.

Comment: @DavidDossot i just tried increasing the timeout seconds now a different message . when i hit the localhost:8081 i am successfully redirected to the Salesforce authorization page but after entering my credentials i get this error message 'Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: String'

Comment: But the root cause is `Connection timed out: connect` as shown above, right?

Comment: @DavidDossot Thats right - i see the connection timedout: connect in the console even after increasing my timeout seconds. I have also updated my question with the URL s i am redirected to .. if that helps ..

Comment: Can you try adding `path="callback"` on the `http:inbound-endpoint` ?

Comment: @DavidDossot no luck :(  deployment fails if i try to deploy the flow. org.mule.api.transport.ConnectorException: There is already a listener registered on this connector on endpointUri: http://localhost:8081/callback. Connector that caused exception is: HttpConnector

Comment: @DavidDossot Where you successfully execute the Oauth flow using Mule ? if so could you shed some light. I am not sure what i am missing. I am stuck in this for a couple of days now

Comment: Last time I used the SFDC connector was 1.5 years ago, had no issue then, although behind a corp firewall. But I can't see what's going on with your config, sorry :'(

Comment: @DavidDossot no problem.. thanks fr your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Mule and the Salesforce Connector 6.2 resolves it.